# Ubuntu 20.04 Boot Fail after DisplayLink Driver Installed HP Spectre

Tags: boot, drivers, 20.04, displaylink

I had been running Xubuntu on version 18.04 on my HP Spectre 15. I was using a USB-C dock to connect the laptop to my other monitors with the DisplayLink driver installed. This was working fine.

I then encountered a number of issues where it would freeze up entirely at the login screen, I couldn't even get to a different tty.

I then decided to remove Xubuntu and install Ubuntu 20.04. The install went fine without a problem, the system had a boot issue which was resolved by adding `nomodeset` to grub. Then, I went to install the DisplayLink driver for my dock, following these instructions: https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649.

This seemed to work fine until I rebooted my laptop and was give a 'ppm init failed' on booting. It won't go any further than that, I can switch tty and do a `sudo displaylink-installer uninstall` to remove the driver and the laptop works fine, but obviously unable to use the dock and therefore my other monitors.

I'm at a bit of a loss; I've tried both proprietary and non-proprietary Nvidia drivers, I did this manually first then by reinstalling Ubuntu in case I did something wrong but that hasn't fixed the problem. Could this have something to do with the `nomodeset` option? I can't think of what else to do so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can attest it has to do with nomodeset. I am having the same problem. Removing nomodeset resolves this, but I have got another problem of random shutdowns on removing nomodeset, so can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the exact same issue on my new acer swift 3 notebook with an amd cpu/gpu. Besides the display link driver giving me a black screen of death the HDMI port on the notebook would also not work. I manged to get both working by doing the following:

- Updating the kernel to 5.6.17 using the method described here: https://linuxhint.com/update_ubuntu_kernel_20_04/ ( I recommend the graphical updater )
- Rebooting into the new kernel (important!)
- Installing the display link drivers by using the unofficial installer available here: https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian

I don't know how applicable this is to your issues tough. Because mine were mostly related to too modern hardware I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up installing a different distribution which worked without a problem, haven't looked at Ubuntu since.

Comment: @SamChapman out of curiosity which distro did you switch to? I was under the impression that the display link driver only works in Ubuntu based distros. Did you choose a distro that is based on Ubuntu 18?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've only just noticed this. I switched to Manjaro and it seems to work okay